# how to combine pipe with one execve

Tags: c, unix

Try to respond to the output of a program and that this should receive the answers but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
int main() {

    char *args[] = {"./a.out", 0};
    int fd1[2], fd2[2];

    if(pipe(fd1) == -1 || pipe(fd2) == -1) {
        perror("error pipe\n");
        return;
    }

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(fd2[0], 0);
        close(fd2[1]);

        execve("./a.out", args, NULL);
    } else {
        dup2(fd1[0], 0);
        close(fd1[0]);

        write(fd2[1], "23", 2);
        write(fd2[1], "A", 1);

        int status;
        wait(&status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well this code is certainly wrong, you're creating 2 pipes but use just one of them. But without you explaining clearly **what** you want to do, it's impossible to tell you how to do it correctly.

Comment: I have tried to only with a pipe, but i have also not succeeded. What I want is that if the program asked what age i have (for example) answer my age.

Comment: so you need to wait for a prompt from your child? then you need 2 pipes, wire one to stdin and the other to stdout before `exec()`ing the program.

Comment: Yes, i need wait for the child. You can give me an example please?

Comment: read from the pipe you wired to your child's `STDOUT_FILENO`, *then* write to the pipe you wired to its `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: I am sorry to say to you that without an example I do not obtain it

Comment: try using the example code foound in the linux programming guide (online at TLDP)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my mistake was not to wrote the newline in the write and therefore did not quite read the invoked program.

```
 int main() {

    char *args[] = {"./a.out", 0};
    int fd1[2];
    if(pipe(fd1) == -1) {
        perror("error pipe\n");
        return;
    }

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(fd1[0], 0);
        close(fd1[0]);
        close(fd1[1]);

        execve("./a.out", args, NULL);
    } else {

        write(fd1[1], "5\n", 2);

        int status;
        wait(&status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```